# Lambda expression error in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

Firstly I would like to apologize to you all because I know that this question has been asked a whole bunch of times. But I dont know much about MVC or .NET or Lambda expressions per se. I am working on a small project and I am stuck at the Lambda expression error as below 
[image]

**EDIT**
**Below is the controller Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVC4Trial.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

namespace MVC4Trial.Controllers
{
    public partial class CallTrackController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Remote_Data()
        {
            return View("AjaxBinding");
        }

        public ActionResult vwCallDetails([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {

            return Json(GetCallDetailsFn().ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }

        private static IEnumerable<CallDetails> GetCallDetailsFn()
        {
            var callData = new CallTrackClassDataContext();
            return callData.CallDetails.Select(calldetail => new CallDetails
            {
                CCCID = calldetail.CCCID,
                Mp3_Url = calldetail.Mp3_Url,
                Index = calldetail.Index,
                Target_Number = calldetail.Target_Number,
                Duration = calldetail.Duration,
                LocalTime = calldetail.LocalTime,
                Site_Name___Address = calldetail.Site_Name___Address,
                Ad_Source_Name = calldetail.Ad_Source_Name,
                Tracking_Number = calldetail.Tracking_Number,
                Caller_Number = calldetail.Caller_Number,
                Available_Feature = calldetail.Available_Feature


            });
        }


     }
}
```

I would like to learn how to fix this error. What am I missing here? Do I need to make any sort of changes on my Model/View/Any other file? Thanks for reading and helping.

Comment: A screenshot is nice, but can you post the text of the code so others wouldn't need to retype it?

Comment: What's the error on the 'Duration' line?  I've notice that other errors will cause linq errors.

Comment: I notice `Duration` is underlined - is there something special about that property?

Comment: Thank you all for helping out so quickly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something wrong with `Duration`. It's underlined in red, indicating that it doesn't exist on the class, or some other issue is causing it to not be recognized. Since there's an error here, the lambda expression doesn't process properly and it's only then that Visual Studio recognizes there error. Essentially, the reported error is masking the true problem. Fix `Duration` or remove it, and the lambda expression will be fine.

For what it's worth though, what you're doing doesn't make much sense. `callData.CallDetails` *already* returns an instance of `CallDetails` (or at least it should, or you should change the name), so using `Select` to return an instance of `CallDetails` populated from an instance of `CallDetails` is superfluous.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for not being more clear. My last comment really depends on what is exactly going on in code I can't see. So there's two possible scenarios:

1) `callData.CallDetails` is an instance of `CallDetails`. If this is the case, using `Select` is a waste of time and code because all you're doing is just converting one instance of `CallDetails` to another. Just doing `return callData.CallDetails;` would have the same effect.

2) `callData.CallDetails` is *not* an instance of `CallDetails`. If this is the case, then you should simply rename the `CallDetails` member of `callData` to avoid the sort of confusion that prompted my comment in the first place.

FWIW: If you really need to map some other type to an instance of `CallDetails` like this, you should look into [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). Writing this code is not only repetitive and time-consuming, but you also make yourself more prone to errors. For example, what if you later change the definition of `CallDetails`? You now got to track down every explicit mapping like this and change that as well, whereas with AutoMapper, you likely can just change the definition and be done.

Comment: I fixed the problem by fixing the Duration Column. I will accept the answer shortly when SO lets me do it. What other change would you suggest to the code to get rid of the "superfluous"ness? I am sorry, I dont sound too technical, but I am a database guy and this is the first time I am playing with apps.

Comment: @rvphx: Perhaps move the copy/conversion code you have in the `Select()` portion to a dedicated method. I'm not sure if you're simply cloning the same class or copying to/from a separate data-transfer object (DTO), so I'm not sure the best place for this method to reside. At the very least it will make your code more readable.